# How to merge a list of maps in java?

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists of maps.

```
List<Map<String,String>> catDataToCache = new ArrayList();
List<Map<String,String>> catDataToCache2 = new ArrayList();
```

Each map looks like this

```
map('referer'=>'abc.com','category'=>'def.com')
```

I have to merge these two. I tried `List.addAll();` However I get a garbled collection.

Comment: What are the rules for the "merge"? What does "garbled" mean?

Comment: Can you define what gets distorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're trying to merge mappings from two or more `Map`s. If so, you do it using `Map#putAll()` without involving `List`s unless the `Map`s are actually stored in there which seems rather unlikely.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("referrer", "abc.com");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("category", "def.com");

Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapping : map3.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(mapping.getKey() + " = " + mapping.getValue());
}
```

***Output** :*

```
category = def.com
referrer = abc.com
```

---

If you're actually getting your `Map`s within a `List`, simply iterate over it and use `putAll()` as shown above for each `Map`. If there are multiple such `List`s, repeat the `Iterator` loop for each one of them.

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

// initialize map1, map2, map3 same as above

listOfMaps.add(map1);
listOfMaps.add(map2);

for (Iterator<Map<String, String>> iterator =
                        listOfMaps.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    map3.putAll(iterator.next());
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapping : map3.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(mapping.getKey() + " = " + mapping.getValue());
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. However I get list of maps from a function so I cannot individually merge those maps

Comment: Ravi has shown you how to solve your problem in principle. In order to generalise the above code you would need to iterate over the maps returned from the method you're calling, and do something like map3.putAll(currentMap), where currentMap is the map for the current iteration.

Comment: @Shades88, I've updated with an example on how to process your map `List`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Map<String,String>> catDataToCache = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<Map<String,String>> catDataToCache2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    List<Map<String,String>> mergedDataToCache = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    mergedDataToCache.addAll(catDataToCache);
    mergedDataToCache.addAll(catDataToCache2);

    Map<String,String> mergedMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(Map<String,String> map:mergedDataToCache){
        mergedMap.putAll(map);
    }
```